# Application has stopped when close button clicked

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing an android app but my app is being stopped

Here is the steps I did: I ...
 1. am using tabbed activity and there is a list view
 2. Each element in listView is registered for context menu
 3. First option is context menu is for editing info for the view
 4. Once it is clicked, it opens another activity(intent is used)

And the error is when I click close button while the new activity is open, I am having error:"Unfortunately app has stopped"

Edit Class:

```
public class Editor extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int position = intent.getIntExtra("POSITION", -1);
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.intentResult);
        t.setText(position+"");
    }
}
```

Intent Call :

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==EDIT_ID){

    }
    else if(item.getItemId()==DELETE_ID){
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Editor.class);
        intent.putExtra("POSITION", acmi.position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

//acmi is just an integer

> Error: 01-21 16:54:59.714 2820-2820/com.example.abu_bakr.darsjadvali
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.abu_bakr.darsjadvali, PID: 2820
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.example.abu_bakr.darsjadvali/com.example.abu_bakr.darsjadvali.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed
>   cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@2e3a8e12
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3033)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an
>   already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@2e3a8e12
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6076)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6099)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3022)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
>                                                                                       at com
>
> .android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)

Comment: post the error logs and bit more code to understand the scenario

Comment: error says  "trying to requery an already closed cursor"  where are using one.

Answer (score 0):

As your error log says, it's a database exception.

Post the complete code of your `MainActivity` so we can understand what's going on